# Calling read from gdb

Tags: gdb

I would like to read from stdout while debugging, but I keep getting back -1. Here is part of my gdb session:

```
(gdb) call fflush(stdout)
$16 = 0
(gdb) p/x malloc(50) 
$17 = 0xb7fff2e0
(gdb) call read(stdout, (void *) 0xb7fff2e0, 49)
$19 = -1
```

I am also under the assumption that if there is nothing in the stdout file, calling read should return zero. I would read from stderr to get more information, but of course this fails as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling read, which expects a file descriptor, yet you are passing a FILE *

Try

```
call read(0, (void *) 0xb7fff2e0, 49)
```

Also, reading for stdout seems odd, vs reading from stdin

Comment: Ah thank you, I actually thought stdout was a file descriptor. I didn't mention this previously, but I called pipe on stdin and stdout before read. It's strange that gdb returned zero (no error) when pipe also expects file descriptors.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question. I use GDB quite a bit, but, honestly, I didn't know about calling a function from it. Lol. We both learned something.

Comment: I love gdb lol. I was debugging an exploit for a security class that relies on two execution threads, and I didn't know how else to simulate this interaction without function calls.